# How apply Discount Sticker(Label,image) on Selected Product or Category

Tags: magento2, image

[image]

I want to this type of the image as a sticker on Product left or Right upper corner. Has any extension or anything else.

Comment: Did you find any free stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily done this by using this extension:
https://amasty.com/product-labels.html#screenshots